# Why Nginx try_files not working as expected?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have elastic beanstalk (eb) launch an instance with an nginx web server and node js app server. If I visit the eb URL (`https://www.my-domain-test.xxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/`), nginx correctly forwards my request (with path `/`) to the node js server. However, when I use route 53 alias record to point a custom domain (`https://test.my_domain.com`) to that eb url (again, with path `/`, just a different hostname), it does not forward the request to the node js server, and it instead returns the `/index.html` in the `root` directive location (and if I delete that file, it returns the default nginx `/index.html` file).

I can debug by adding `return 200 "Server info - $host, $uri";` to various locations in the config file to see if the code is reached. I confirmed the eb url makes it to `location @nodejs {}` directive, but the custom domain does not, but both `$uri`s are `/`.

It seems like both should work identically and forward the request to the node js server, which is my goal. What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Below is my nginx config:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    port_in_redirect off;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  600;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
    proxy_send_timeout 600;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;

    log_format healthd '$msec"$uri"'
                       '$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"'
                       '$http_x_forwarded_for';

  upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
  }

  server {
    listen 8080;
    client_max_body_size 60M;

    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
    proxy_send_timeout 600;
    proxy_read_timeout 600;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;

    root /var/app/current/public;

    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
        set $hour $4;
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @nodejs;
        client_max_body_size 60M;

        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
          add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

        #redirects if host doesn't start with www, unless it is test subdomain
        set $is_subdomain_redirect  "0";

        if ($host !~* ^www\.) {
          set $is_subdomain_redirect  "1";
        }

        if ($host ~* ^test\.) {
          set $is_subdomain_redirect  "0";
        }

        if ($is_subdomain_redirect ~* "1") {
          add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
          return 301 $http_x_forwarded_proto://www.$host$request_uri;
        }
    }

    location @nodejs {
        proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;

    location /public {
        alias /var/app/current/public;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Your `if` blocks inside `location /` will bypass the `try_files` statement. It's usually best to [avoid using `if`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) inside a location block.

Comment: @RichardSmith That was indeed the issue. Thank you! Please submit it as an answer so I can accept it for you. :)